# How to find all files with the same extension within a directory

Tags: command-line

I want to search for all `.conf` files in `/etc/`.

I tried `grep -r *.conf /etc`, but the result isn't right.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
```

This will list all files with the extension `.txt`.

The `.` at the start denotes the current directory. `find` searches recursively in all the directories below the given path. If you want the search to start somewhere other than the current working directory, specify the path, for example:

```
find /etc -type f -name "*.conf"
```

This searches the `/etc` directory and all its subdirectories for regular files with the `.conf` extension.

Comment: It works. Are there any alternatives for this command?

Comment: You can take a look at [Locate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate).

Comment: @AdrianGeorge `find` is so widely used, so well documented, and has so many StackOverflow/Exchange posts about it that it'd be harder to find something easier to work with. Just about anything you'd want to do has been written up online somewhere.

Comment: fd is faster and simpler to use.https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Comment: I wonder why the `-type f` command is necessary? I checked the manual and I'm not sure what the advantage of using it is. Is it to omit symbolic links? I'd think folder's names usually don't have extensions (and if they have, like `.git`, I'd want to finde them). I looks to me, in this case, that adding `-type f` is overly specific.

Comment: @Turtle10000 `-type f Search for files`.

Comment: @Turtle10000 looking into the man page of `find` with the `-type` the possible file types are: 
             b       block special |
             c       character special |
             d       directory | 
             f       regular file | 
             l       symbolic link | 
             p       FIFO | 
             s       socket

Answer (score 11):

`grep` searches the *contents* of files, not the file names.

To find all `.conf` files in `/etc/` you'll want find:

```
find /etc -name "*.conf"
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd personally use `find`, but you can glob for these things too:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls /etc/{,**/}*.conf
```

And you can use locate and it's fast but not reliable.

```
locate '/etc/**.conf'
```

Comment: Why isn't `locate` reliable?

Comment: @Giraldi `locate` relies on the mlocate database to have been updated recently to be accurate. By default that is only scheduled to update once a day (though you can force it manually with `updatedb`).

Comment: @Oli not true on macs though, right? think mac os keeps mlocate updated

Answer (score 1):

The find command is slow, use this command will give you result immediately:

```
locate "/etc/*.conf"
```

More info about `locate` command (in `mlocate` package) can be found here: https://medium.com/@thucnc/the-fastest-way-to-find-files-by-filename-mlocate-locate-commands-55bf40b297ab

Comment: `locate` was mentioned two years ago: http://askubuntu.com/a/333728/158442

Comment: Shouldn't it have two asterisks (`locate "/etc/**.conf"`) if you want to search recursively like the question mentions?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple `ls` command:

```
ls /etc/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will return all files and folders ending in `.conf`:

```
ls -lR /etc | grep ".conf$"
```

To find only files, run:

```
find /etc -type f -name '*.conf'
```